How do I deal with a datetime2 date in Access VBA?
From the Microsoft docs, they recommend to use datetime2 for new work going forward. I've started modifying some of our stored procedures to use this. I now ran into a problem where a Microsoft Access form is trying to do CDATE() on a datetime2 value and returning a type mismatch error. How is this commonly handled? Or should I ignore what Microsoft recommends and just use a datetime? I also tried using DateValue(), but it returns the same error.
?CDate("2024-06-04 07:26:19.1466667")
Type mismatch

?DateValue("1-1-1900")
1/1/1900 

?DateValue("2024-06-04 07:26:19.1466667")
Type mismatch


DateTime2 isn't supported in VBA, only - with some limitations and by using the latest ODBC drivers - in Access SQL.
If you don't need milliseconds, stick with DateTime in SQL Server and save your precious time for other tasks.
If you do need milliseconds, VBA can handle this nicely, though only with custom functions as in my library at GitHub: VBA.Date.

The issue with your code isn't really related to any SQL Server data type, since there are no tables etc. involved.
To work with datetime2 in Access:
1: Use the current ODBC driver: Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Older drivers, especially the ancient {SQL Server} driver, can't handle datetime2.
2: If you don't actually need milliseconds, use datetime2(0) for zero fractional seconds precision.
